# How to insert link on cursor position of tiptap editor in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I'm new to VueJS and even more to the tiptap editor that my team is using. I need to make a function that inserts a link at the cursor position within the editor.

I do know about the Link() function with the floating menu bubble. That's already working. But in the web application, they would like to have a pop-up with an option to fill in a display text and a corresponding link, which should be inserted to the editor at cursor position.

Currently, I already have this code:

```
insertLink(value) {
  let linkToAdd = '<a href="' + value.insertLinkUrl + '" target="_blank">' + value.insertLinkText + '</a>';
  let editorHtml = this.editor.getHTML();
  editorHtml += linkToAdd;
  this.editor.setContent(editorHtml);
}
```

But, now it appends to the end of the content and also creates a new paragraph tag in which it stores the new generated HTML(?).

Can anybody help me point a little more in the correct direction? That would be very nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out links in tiptap right now and it doesn't seem trivial. Do you have a good source of how to insert a simple editable link string (or a popup to fill out)?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer and I don't know if it will help anyone in vuejs. This is how i implemented in react.

```
import Link from "@tiptap/extension-link";

export const CustomLink = Link.extend({
  addCommands() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      addLink: function (options) {
        return ({ tr, commands }) => {
          commands.insertContent(
            `<a href='${options.href}' class="custom-link">${options.href}</a>`,
            {
              parseOptions: {
                preserveWhitespace: false,
              },
            }
          );
        };
      },
    };
  },
});
```